# Express logging with storing the request information

Tags: node.js, logging, express

## Background

Yes, there are a lot of different Node.js logging library winston, bunyan and console.log. It's easy to log down the information of the specific request when it has called and when and what information would be in response.

## The problem

The problem begins with the sub function calls. When under one request your calling multiple functions which also uses the same logging, how would you pass the request meta - data to these log calls (function parameters seems to be one possible way but these are really messy) ?

## Example

Small visual for coders:

```
// Middleware to set some request based information
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.rid = 'Random generated request id for tracking sub queries';
});

app.get('/', function (req, rest) {
   
  async.series({
    'users': async.apply(db.users.find),
    'posts': async.apply(db.posts.find),
  }, function (err, dbRes) {
     console.log('API call made ', req.rid)
     res.end(dbRes);

  });


});


// Now the database functions are in other file but we also need to track down the request id in there
(db.js)

module.exports = {
   users: {
      find: function () {
         console.log('Calling users listing ', req.rid); // ERROR this is not possible to access, not in this scope 
         // Make query and return result
      }

   },

   posts: {
      find: function () {
         console.log('Calling post listing ', req.rid); // ERROR this is not possible to access, not in this scope 
         // Make query and return result
      }

   }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can log your requests with simple conf in your app.js with;

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

However, you need to provide logs for specific functions in your controller.

Comment: Yes, actually after some search found some possible solutions: one includes the usage of domains which allows to store data but this is hacky way. Currently the best solution what I have found is to use this library https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage.

Comment: Well actually this does not solve the problem, the only way to solve this is to currently pass the object reference to all functions that use logging(WOW sounds the worst plan ever).

Comment: In your question title, you want to store request informtion. If you want to store sub calls, you need to pass some extra vars to logger. Like you said object id.