# Is there a neat way to do contextual logging in a concurrent system?

Tags: node.js, logging, concurrency

My specific example is for Node.js, but I assume the same problem exists in any event-loop-based system.

Consider the following simple application:

```
var logger = loggingmodule.Logger();

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    req.id = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(10).toString('hex');
    var log = logger.transaction(req.id);

    loadSomeAsyncData(log, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return bailout(err, req, res);

        doSomeAsyncAction(log, req.url, data.action, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return bailout(err, req, res);

            hydrateResultWithMoreAsyncData(log, data, result, onMoreData);

            function onMoreData(err, moreData) {
                if (err) return bailout(err, req, res);

                result.data = moreData;

                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    data: data,
                    result: result,
                }));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

- The logging module has a `transaction` method which returns a contextual logger that prefixes all lines with the same token
- To correlate any actions taken during the request, we need to pass this logger around
- These actions then also need to pass the logger on to their dependents
- Everything needs to accept a logger argument somehow

**Question: Is there an alternative to passing the logger to every single function?**

The closest thing I can think of would be something like a thread-local binding - but of course no such abstraction does or afaik could exist for Node.js

Comment: I just came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224641/express-logging-with-storing-the-request-information - which asks a similar question but with a bit less detail.

Comment: And it turns out someone has managed to get something like a thread-local binding somehow! https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage